# Aligning Instances' Axes Inward in Geometry Nodes

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes, vector

I'm trying to get all of my Geometry Nodes instances to point inwards along a Spiral Curve. With my current setup, they are tilting all around the Spiral rather than just being fixed facing inwards.
[image: Geometry Nodes Setup]

How can I get them to rotate along the Spiral Curve and just point inwards: not tilt? I was able to create the desired effect using a Circular Array (image below), but I need to use Geometry Nodes.

[image: Geometry Nodes Desired]

Here is my .blend file:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to align the instances inward, you'll need the vectors that point inwards (or towards the center of the spiral). In this case, you can re-use the position of the points that belong to the spiral curve, get rid of the Z-axis, flip the other two remaining axes and then normalize it to get the needed directional vectors. This node setup below should be able to help you with your problem.
[image]

Comment: Great work! Thank you very much :)